# C Programming Switch Case

Tags: c, switch-statement, case, if-statement

C Programming

How to change this if else condition to switch case??

```
    if(n >= 10 && n <= 20){price=2.00;}
    else if(n > 20){price=3.00;}
    else {price=1.00;}
```

Comment: afaik switch in c only supports constants for cases, which means your code cant be put in a switch case

Comment: You can't. Not unless you have an upper limit to the values of `n`.

Comment: You cannot - anyway why would you want to?

Comment: @EdHeal In C it doesn't make sense to `switch`, but e.g. Go has a generalized `switch` that makes this kind of if-else-else-... easier to read (a bit like Lisp's `cond`).

Comment: If he really wanted to, he COULD do it using two scitches. And by transforming 3 lines of code into a big waste of space !

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not in any meaningful way that would improve the code. Switch is best when the number of cases is limited, and when the values themselves have meaning.

Since your code has two "open-ended" cases (`n > 20` and `else`, i.e. `n < 10`), you can't solve it with a `switch` which only supports one such catch-all, the `default` case.

Answer (score 0):

It can not. The case argument in switch statement can be only exact value, no comparison is accepted